# Pagination not showing at all

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have this function in functions.php

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

and in a custom post archive i have this code...

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'weddings'), 'posts_per_page' => 2 , 'paged' => $paged ) );

if(have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="mosaic__item">My item</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>
```

When i call the function 'kriesi_pagination' nothing happens. It displays nothing at all. I'm pretty sure i've used this code on different projects i had before, and everything was ok. What am i missing?

UPDATE: i've tried `<div class="next"><?php next_posts_link('Next Page &rsaquo;') ?></div>` and it only returns `<div class="next"></div>`

Comment: enable WP_DEBUG to true and see exact error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Re-installed wordpress. Now pagination is working.